# Use ggplot2 in RCommander

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-commander

Is it possible to tune RCommander to obtain similar graphs as obtained by using ggplot2? Does RCommander use some plotting package like ggplot2 to plot the graph?

I could script in RCommander to use ggplot2 but the whole point behind using RCommander is that I don't want to code in R.

Comment: You know why. R is way better than Excel.

Comment: In my view it is a valid question. If you want to use R through a GUI to get a specific subset of R functionality, that is fine by me. Probably you aren't going to get the kind of power and flexibility out of R that is available, but if the small subset is exactly what you need that is great.

Comment: There are also reasons not to use Excel, for example http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/csdana/v52y2008i10p4570-4578.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `KMggplot2` plugin for `Rcmdr`? Here's a link to the package on CRAN:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcmdrPlugin.KMggplot2/

According to its reference manual, `KMggplot2` is

> is an R Commander plug-in for Kaplan-Meier plots **and other plots** by
>   using the ggplot2 package in GUI interface.

Comment: Hi.  How can you get something like par(mfrow=c(2,2)) using  menus, without writing it?

Comment: @skan do you mean in R Commander? I don't know. You should try asking a new question. It's totally unrelated to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the [deducer GUI](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.PlotBuilder) has the ability to build `ggplot2` plots using the GUI system. This would help you avoid writing code. If you are serious about data analysis, learning to code some R would be very beneficial though.